# On-prem and Cloud Consolidated Data in Report

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have  Teradata  database that sits on on-premise and data is on ADLS Gen2. I need to show that in

Tableau report that should dynamically show consolidated data in the dashboard. What is approach should I follow. Appreciate your help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

Do you want to connect to a Teradata DB? This link should help: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_teradata.htm

Do you want to connect to Azure data lake directly? This link should help: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_azure_data_lake_gen2.htm

Do you want to understand how link data from two source in the Tableau Datamodel?
Multiple options, all explained here and depending on your need, one or the other should be used (or a combination!): https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datasource_prepare.htm

--> Do be aware that the data mixing & connecting capabilities of Tableau are somewhat limited compared to some other tools

Do you want to understand how to create reports? There are plenty of tutorials available, a quick google search should help you out.

Comment: Sure let me know if you need more help . If it helps, flagging as "correct" or upvoting would be appreciated :-)